# Why don't arrays have string index signatures?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array that I want to reuse as an object by adding properties to it. Consider the following example.

```js
const arr = ["Hi", "my", "name", "is"];
arr.name = "Peter";
```

In TypeScript this can be typed using index signatures. To cover the numeric and string indices I use the more general string index signature. However, upon trying to assign an array to the interface, TypeScript gives an error.

```js
interface StringArray {
    [index: string]: string | number;
}

const arr: StringArray = ["Hi", "my", "name", "is"];
// Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'StringArray'.
// Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'.(2322)
arr.name = "Peter";
```

I included the `number` type in the string index signature such that `arr.length` is covered as well.

---

My reasoning why this should work is the following. In JavaScript numeric indices in the bracket property accessor are converted to strings, i.e. `arr[0]` is converted to `arr["0"]`. Given this, I would have expected a string index signature to be a superset of the numeric index signature, such that it covers all numeric indices as well as string indices.

In other words, if the following works

```js
interface NumbersArray {
    [index: number]: number;
}

const arr: NumbersArray = [10, 20, 30];
```

then this should also work (which it doesn't)

```js
interface NumbersArray {
    [index: string]: number;
}

const arr: NumbersArray = [10, 20, 30];
// Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'StringArray'.
// Index signature is missing in type 'number[]'.(2322)
```

Even the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) states that the type of the numeric index signature must be a subtype of the string index signature for this very reason.

> The type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer.

So my question boils down to the following.

Why don't arrays have a string index signature in TypeScript, when string indices are a superset of numeric indices?

**PS**. I don't want to circumvent type checking using a type assertion like `as any` on the array. Please don't suggest type assertions.

Comment: `const arr: string[] & {name? :string} = ...`? Or for an array, the index type should be `[index: number]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but that covers only a single `name` property. I want to be able add more additional properties later of which I don't know the name yet.

Comment: At that point you might as well use `any`.

Comment: Does copying TypeScript into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/  and seeing the generated JavaScript not give you the answer you seek as to 'why'?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not really, since I could say I want to limit myself to only be able to add properties of type `string | number`.

Comment: @JGFMK The generated JavaScript is the same TypeScript with types removed. I don't see how it would answer my question?

Comment: Often I found when things didn't work in TypeScript as I had expected. I found -running it thru the Playground and seeing the resulting JavaScript gave me the answer to why things didn't work. Sorry it didn't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#332-array-types) can't have a string index by design:

```
interface Array<T> {  
    length: number;  
    [x: number]: T;  
    // Other members  
}
```

Don't confuse the type of the index value with the type of index.

In type theory the index type is a [type constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor). In this case it builds from the type of the index value (`number` or `string`).

`string` and `number` are unrelated types but the type `IndexType<number>` of a numeric index is a subtype
of `IndexType<string>` because of how it works javascript indexes: the numeric index value `n` may be used
as the string index `"n"` to access an `Array<T>` element.

If you want an object that is an array and has an unknow number of properties use
an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

An array of string object with additional properties of type string:

```
type StringArrayExt = Array<string> & { [index: string]: string };

let arr = ['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is'] as StringArrayExt;
arr.name = 'Peter';
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution. This might be the best way currently, even though it still uses a type assertion.

However it still doesn't answer my initial question. If string indices are a superset of numeric indices (since numeric ones are converted to strings), why doesn't the string index signature cover the numeric index signature. I edited my question with an example (after the horizontal line) with what I would have expected to work.

Comment: Oh, I got it now! The string index signature really covers only string indices like `arr["0"]` while the numeric index signature covers only numeric indices like `arr[0]`. Just the *type* of the numeric index signature must be a subtype of the type of the string index signature, because `arr[0]` is a shorthand for `arr["0"]`. I had falsely assumed that the *indices* covered by the numeric index signature would be a subset of the ones covered by the string index signature while infact they are disjoint sets.